# Convert string with index in brackets to JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, split

I have various strings with numbers in brackets like `"[4]Motherboard, [25]RAM"` how can I convert such a string to a JSON array (keeping both ids and values) like this:

```
{"data":[
  {"id":"4","item":"Motherboard"},
  {"id":"25","item":"RAM"}
]};
```

I'm tried using `split(",")` to create the array but I really can't find out how to get the inner data in this case.

Comment: Go with the _obvious_ solution and let us know what have you tried..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function toArray(string) {
    return {
        data: string.split(",").map(function(str) {
            str = str.trim();
            return {
                id: str.substring(1, str.indexOf("]")),
                item: str.substring(str.indexOf("]") + 1),
            };
        }),
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here one way to do it. The pattern `\[(\d+?)\](.+)` works like this:

1. `(…)` is a capture group. Just means whatever matches within the brackets will be a token in the result.
2. `\d` means a digit
3. `\d+` means a digit, one or more times
4. `\d+?` means a digit, one or more times, but as few as possibile before the pattern matches something else.
5. `.+` means any character, one or more times.

`[` and `]` have a special meaning in regular expression, so if you actually want to match the characters themselves, you need to *escape* them like so `\[` and `\]`.

The double backslashes `\\` are just a JS oddity when defining a regex via a string as opposed to using a `/literal/`. Just two ways of saying the same thing.

There's plenty of resources to learn regex syntax, and http://regex101.com is a great place to play with patterns and experiment.

```js
var input = "[4]Motherboard, [25]RAM";
var pattern = '\\[(\\d+?)\\](.+)';
var result = input.split(',').map(function (item) {
  var matches = item.match(new RegExp(pattern));
  return {id: matches[1], val: matches[2]};
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Good one but can you please explain the regex a bit? I know it's a simple case, but still...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression, which takes the number and the string, and assign it as property to an object.

```js
var string = "[4]Motherboard, [25]RAM",
    data = string.split(', ').map(function (a) {
        var p = a.match(/^\[(\d+)\](.+)$/);
        return { id: p[1], item: p[2] };
    });
console.log(data);
```

Comment: This does not match the format in the question. You have `{ "4": "Motherboard" }`, but it asks for `{ "id": "4", "item": "Motherboard" }`.